# Cannot figure out why page has scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am having an issue with a simple single page website. It can be found [here](http://bramvanroy.be/). I tried making a fiddle, but was not able to reproduce the problem.

As you can see, a scrollbar appears (tested on Chrome and FF). But I cannot find where/how it originates! I have tried a lot of `overflow: hidden` (which I would like to avoid) and cleafixes, but nothing helps. Can anyone locate the problem?

EDIT: I know the 100% height on the body has an effect on it, but this *should not* be a problem. Body should be as tall as html. But for some reason body has a margin-top, or html has a padding-top. And I do not know what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set a height of 100% to the body AND in your #main-wrapper you set a margin of 20px (top and bottom), with that in mind, since your body tag is the parent of the main-wrapper, it now has a top margin of 20px so the final height is 100% + 20px and that's causing the scrollbar. To solve that, just remove the 100% height or replace the "margin: 20px auto" with "margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0".

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `height:100%` from body or HTML.

Comment: See my edit. I know that's a possibility, but that is not the problem - so I rather not.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your "height:100%" on the body is causing it to create that scroll bar; try removing that.

Comment: See my edit. I know that's a possibility, but that is not the problem - so I rather not.

Comment: Actually, it is the problem, since the body is taking up 100% of the parent element, which is the html, and you have a margin on your #main-wrapper that is pushing the rest of your document down. In effect, that causes your <html> to become larger, and finally, the body will need to go down further to accommodate for the 100% height.

take a look at http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557199/xhtml-html-element-with-100-height-causing-scrollbars to understand better for why that problem is occurring